# How to make a modal background fill the entire page, even when there is a scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a modal for editing some content, and while I want the background for the modal to fill the entire visible screen, the form (the modal content) has a fixed height.

Issues arise when the viewport has a smaller height. There is a scroll after opening the modal, and when you scroll, part of the background doesn't show at the bottom.

How can I make it stretch to fill the entire height of the body element? Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yzhm7v12/3/) and my code below:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const modal = document.querySelector('.modal');
  modal.classList.toggle('hidden');
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
}

.flex {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #999999;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.modal {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.modal.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.modal_content {
  margin: auto 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #999999;
  border: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="flex">
    <p>Click anywhere in the document to add/remove the modal</p>
    <p>Resize the window so the modal is too tall, then try to scroll</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal hidden">
    <div class="modal_content">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: you could block scroll event when modal appears or just give the background a fixed position, 100vh height, 100% width and top and left position of 0px

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could resolve this issue by setting on the modal a position fixed instead of an absolute one as you did. Like so:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function() {
    const modal = document.querySelector('.modal');
  modal.classList.toggle('hidden');
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
}
.flex {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #999999;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.modal {
  position: fixed; /* line I changed */
  overflow:auto; /* line I added */
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.modal.hidden {
  display: none;
}
.modal_content {
  margin: auto 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #999999;
  border: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
 <p>Click anywhere in the document to add/remove the modal</p>
 <p>Resize the window so the modal is too tall, then try to scroll</p>
</div>
<div class="modal hidden">
 <div class="modal_content">
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That almost does it, I added `overflow: scroll` to the modal as well, as `position: fixed` prevented scrolling, and now it works fine. Thanks!  

Edit: could someone please explain why `position: absolute` breaks this?

Comment: Yeah you were right. I added that in the answer as well. Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Everything is on its place but you need to use `position:fixed` not `absolute`

```
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

when using `absolute` then you'll be placing your modal absolutely inside `relative or fixed or another absolute` positioned parent or grandparent of that modal,

but using `fixed` you're placing your modal relative to `browser window` not its  `div` or other sorts of parent